# how fetch data async in initstate and then create build method and pass data?

Tags: flutter, async-await

how fetch data async in initstate and then create build method and pass data?

i want get data async from API in initstate and then create build method this is my code:

```
Future<void> getCurrency() async {
NetworkHelper networkHelper = await NetworkHelper(
    url: 'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/BTC/USD?apikey=$kApiKey');
var currencyData = await networkHelper.getData();
currencyrate = currencyData['rate'];
```

}

late double rate;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
body: SafeArea(
child: Center(
child: Text(
'1 BTC = **$rate** USD',
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black),
),
),
));
}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or you could use a **FutureBuilder** widget, which could just unwrap the data your calling inside that method; you could just return it as a Future of what your data is and the **FutureBuilder** can take care of it, as in:

```dart
Future<double> getCurrency() async {
   NetworkHelper networkHelper = await NetworkHelper(
    url: 'https://rest.coinapi.io/v1/exchangerate/BTC/USD?apikey=$kApiKey');
   var currencyData = await networkHelper.getData();
   double currencyrate = currencyData['rate'];
   return currencyrate;
}
```

Then inside your **build** method:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: getCurrency(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            var rate = snapshot.data as double;
            return Center(
              child: Text('1BTC = $rate USD', 
                 style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black)
            );
          }

          return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
      )
    )
  );
}
```